# how to replace html tag in jquery without replace content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wonder how to change the HTML tag without replacing the contents. I did something like this:

```js
$('#test > span').replaceWith('<div>' + $('#test > span').html() +'</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>hello2</span>
  <span>hello3</span>
</div>
```

Works, but still displays the first value (look code snippet). I think I need to merge `.replaceWith()` with `$(this)` but I can't quite do it.

Answer (score 3):

To do what you require you can pass a function to `replaceWith()`. This function accepts two arguments, the index of the current element and its content, and returns the new element to make the replacement. As such you can use the second argument to change the parent tag while keeping the same content, like this:

```js
$('#test > span').replaceWith((i, content) => `<div>${content}</div>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>hello2</span>
  <span>hello3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a RegExp to replace all `<span></span>` with `<div></div>` in the innerHTML:

```js
// jQuery version

$('#btnReplaceHTML').click(() => {
  const re = /(<\/?)span(>)/gm
  $('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(re, '$1div$2'));
})



/*
// "Vanilla" JavaScript version

document.getElementById('btnReplaceHTML').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const re = /(<\/?)span(>)/gm
  const elem = document.getElementById('test');
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(re, '$1div$2');
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>hello2</span>
  <span>hello3</span>
</div>
<button id="btnReplaceHTML">replace HTML</button>
```